# How to set up Dns Server for resolving one name

Tags: dns

Some background.

My software can be downloaded onto a music server (black box linux based machine) using a binary that I dont have access to, within the binary my servername ([www.jthink.net](http://www.jthink.net)) is hardcoded, I cannot change it.

I switched my old server to a new server (so that i could support SSL) and after the switch the download from the music server stopped working even though wasn't using SSL url and non SSL still works, similar downloads from the website worked fine so could not work out problem, and I had to swap back to old server.

So now I want to test download from the new server (that currently has name test.jthink.net) to determine the problem before switching but I cannot change the music server.

And the /etc/hosts file is read only firmware and cannot be modified.

I am using a Fritz!box router and this has option to use alternative dns server, so I was wondering **if I could setup a super simple dns server just to reroute jthink.net to the ipaddress of test.jthink.net**

Comment: Why close it is a clear question and an answer would be useful for other developers, and I have added concrete background information so thjat the reason for the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [pi-hole](https://docs.pi-hole.net/) can do as you requested.

Install [pi-hole](https://docs.pi-hole.net/) which will serve as your DNS server and configure your router to use it as its DNS server. Afterwards add a [Local DNS Record](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/documentation-on-local-dns-records/33777/5) from your old server DNS to your new server IP

Comment: where should i ibstall pi-hole?

Comment: you can install it where ever as long as your instance have access to it and the pi-hole have connection to the internet

Comment: Sorry picked wrong answer, created new bounty i will give to yo when expires.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a simple DNS server with [BIND](https://www.isc.org/bind/) in a machine and use it as the DNS server for your router. Checkout the article [here](https://opensource.com/article/17/4/build-your-own-name-server).